Anchor test devnet fail
I tried a few ways but it didn't work, I had problems running anchor tests on devnet environment. Can anyone help me? Thanks a lot
To resume a deploy, pass the recovered keypair as the
[BUFFER_SIGNER] to solana program deploy or solana program write-buffer'. Or to recover the account's lamports, pass it as the [BUFFER_ACCOUNT_ADDRESS] argument to solana program close`.
Error: 42 write transactions failed
There was a problem deploying: Output { status: ExitStatus(unix_wait_status(256)), stdout: "", stderr: "" }.

What version of Solana and anchor are you using

i use  1.18.24 version

Try downgrading to 1.18.11 and redeploy

@Jimii I received 1 error:
Error: RPC request error: cluster version query failed: error sending request for url (http://127.0.0.1:8899/): error trying to connect: tcp connect error: Connection refused (os error 111)
There was a problem deploying: Output { status: ExitStatus(unix_wait_status(256)), stdout: "", stderr: "" }.

From the error, it looks like your Anchor.toml is still pointing towards localnet
Update your Anchor.toml config's provider section to point to devnet
[provider]
cluster = "devnet"
wallet = "~/.config/solana/id.json"


i tried, not working

is your config also pointing to devnet?

yes
RPC URL: https://api.devnet.solana.com
WebSocket URL: wss://api.devnet.solana.com/ (computed)

try downgrading to 1.17.34
